# Export vertices connections (triangles) and vertex colors

Tags: paraview

I have a .vtk file which I have uploaded into paraview and generated isosurfaces. I was able to export the value, normals, and points of the isosurfaces. However, I need the triangles (integer representation of how the vertices connect to eachother) so I can reconstruct the image in another software. A bonus would also be to get the colors (rgba) or the vertices as well.

So far I have figured out how to load the data, get the view I would like, use the python trace tool to generate an automated python script that reproduces my work, and how to export the data mentioned above. However, I can't figure out how to get triangle information.

I found the question below which was similar, but I am so unfamiliar with paraview the solution remains a mystery. I think though that a python call to export data is in the right direction...

[Extract Triangles IDs from VTU file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617015/extract-triangles-ids-from-vtu-file)

Your help is greatly appreciated!

## Updates

### 1

I think I have found the color and triangle data by saving data as a  `.ply`  file. I am writing a script that brings the  `.csv`  data and  `.ply`  data together. This seems wonky to need to saved data as two file types to get the necessary information... but perhaps there is a good reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I came up with so far is to use the `File -> Save data` command and save a `.csv` and a `.ply` file of the data of interest.

- The `.csv` contains: points and normals
- The `.ply` contains: points, colors and triangles

By post processing the two files I was able to get the data I needed to recreate the figures in my other program.

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but this bandaid works for the moment. It isn't too bad ad the action can all be scripted too with the Paraview trace tool.